# Buildroot Config Option for applying custom patch

Tags: buildroot

I am new to buildroot and working to build Linaro with buildroot ..I have multiple fragment  kernel config files and specified that in buildroot defconfig.

I have specified a custom kernel patches directory with BR2_LINUX_PATCH_DIR .

I dont have some of the config flags not set which are supposed to be there in the .config files..so i suspect that the Patches are applied successfully..so i tried giving a non existing location as Linux Patch dir and it does not give any error..

Is there anything other than giving value to BR2_LINUX_PATCH_DIR and what should be the format of the dir structure...in buildroot manual it says it should be 
Package_name/patch name..For linux what should be the package name? It should be the same with which linux dir is created.for example for me it is linux-custom

Plz suggest and guide me in this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is named `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_PATCH`, there is nothing named `BR2_LINUX_PATCH_DIR`. It applies all patches listed in this option (if those are files), or all files named `*.patch` if what's given in this option is a directory. See the code in `linux/linux.mk`:

```
define LINUX_APPLY_LOCAL_PATCHES
        for p in $(filter-out ftp://% http://% https://%,$(LINUX_PATCHES)) ; do \
                if test -d $$p ; then \
                        $(APPLY_PATCHES) $(@D) $$p \*.patch || exit 1 ; \
                else \
                        $(APPLY_PATCHES) $(@D) `dirname $$p` `basename $$p` || exit 1; \
                fi \
        done
endef
```

Also, I would recommend that you watch the output of Buildroot: it shows everything it is doing, especially it lists the patches it applied. Look at the line `>>> linux .... Patching`, which is the marker for the beginning of the patching step of the linux package.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have given the patch dir location with BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_PATCH , but looking at the log it seems there is something wrong because below code should show the dir location as well: 
for p in  ; do if test -d $p ; then support/scripts/apply-patches.sh

Comment: Now, the dir location is not displayed, but Buildroot shows a message for each patch applied.

Comment: I had to run `make linux-dirclean && make linux-rebuild` after modifying `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_PATCH`.